# Why does the message BC30560 'mymodule_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP' come up sometimes then go away?

Tags: asp.net

Often when making changes to a VS2008 ASP.net project we get a message like:

BC30560: 'mymodule_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.

This goes away after a recompile or sometimes just waiting 10 seconds and refreshing the page.

Any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility:

http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/157050-BC30560-mycontrolascx-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-ASP/

Seemed to have some success with changing

```
src="mycontrol.ascx.cs"
```

to

```
CodeBehind="mycontrol.ascx.cs"
```

Comment: It says "the directive is missing a src attribute" if I change it

Answer (score 30):

I recently came across this problem and it was only happening on one server even though all were running the same code.  I thoroughly investigated the problem to make sure there were no user controls with clashing names, temp files were cleared out, etc.

The only thing that solved the problems (it seems permanently) is changing the batch attribute of the compilation element to false in the web.config, as suggested in the following link:

http://personalinertia.blogspot.com/2007/06/there-bug-in-compiler.html

```
<compilation debug="true" batch="false">
```

I firmly believe that this is in fact a bug in the compiler as suggested on that site.

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted solution. the currently accepted solution did not resolve the error for me (and, given the number of upvotes here, for others as well)

Comment: Nothing on this page worked for me except this answer. This question should be updated and someone should make this the accepted answer. It would save people a lot of time farting around with wrong answers.

Comment: For me the effect of this attribute was that the project built in VS, but still threw the same error when running in IIS.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue on a server where batch is set to false.

Comment: This worked for us. We were switching between two user controls assigned to the same identifier for testing.

Comment: This works but compiling becomes really slow...

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Problem popped up after years of website functioning correcting.

Answer (score 14):

I just solved this problem with the assistance following link: 
http://www.netomatix.com/development/usercontrols2.aspx

In a nutshell, your class is called MyModule.  However, if you do not specify the ClassName property in the @Control directive, the compiler may append _ascx to the control's class, which results in MyModule_ascx.  Since the page can't find MyModule_ascx, it blows up in your face.  You need to explicitly tell it the ClassName...

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MyModule.ascx.vb" ClassName="MyModule" %>
```

Comment: I've had the same issue and used this as a fix. I can't confirm if it will work as the issue happens randomly but it looks like the most reasonable explanation of why I've received these errors. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I've just suffered this.  Stuff that worked fine and was untouched for months started randomly failing after some unrelated updates.  I'd recompile and the problem would disappear only to reappear somewhere else.

I seem to have resolved it by clearing out the ASP.NET temporary folder, e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.xxxxx\Temporary ASP.NET Files.  This required an IIS restart to really clean it out.

**Update:**  I tried adding `tempDirectory="e:\someotherfolder"` to the `compilation` element of the web.config and that seems to have had some success.  Also added `batch="false"` but not sure if that's had an effect.

Comment: Deleting "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MySiteName" solved it for me. There was a corrupt compilation in there and VS would not override it with new compile directive.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem sometimes too.  If I remember correctly it was caused by something like the following:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="_Default" %>
```

or perhaps

```
<%@ Page ClassName="_Default" %>
```

Or something like that.  I'm not 100% sure which attribute it was (it's been a while).

But look look for something like _Default in your Page directive and replace them with actual class names in all of your files.  For some reason, ASP.Net doesn't always interpret the _Default correctly, yielding temporary ambiguous references.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the two previous answers, you'll most probably have a "copy and pasted" copy of an existing page in the same site, and this will then contain the same @Page directives which will lead to a clashing of functions (especially because everything in .Net defaults to Partial Classes.) This little gem has bitten me all-too-often.

Just update the "Inherits" to point to something specific to your page (i.e.: your page name prefixed by an underscore -- as it's more-often-than-not guaranteed to be unique), and ensured that you haven't got two Public Partial Classes named the same in different code-behind files (otherwise Page_Load in _Default [default.aspx], will clash with Page_Load in _Default [copy of default.aspx])

Answer (score 1):

Try to change web.config, set batch to false

```
<compilation batch="false">
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was a red herring. In reality one of the user controls had errors caused by .NET 2.,0 to 4.5 migration, which had to be fixed in the code, but VS threw this misleading error messages. After multiple attempts to upgrade the projects it finally started erroring on the actual lines of code, but I don't know how to reproduce this after hours of frustration and fruitless attempts to apply solutions from all over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild Solution worked for me.

Comment: That is not solution... Sometime it comes up again...

Answer (score -1):

Also ran into this with MasterPages on projects that were originally .net 1.1 and 2.0 projects and later converted. In both cases, the @MasterType directive referenced the virtualpath. I changed to <%@ MasterType TypeName="MasterPages_MasterPage" %>, cleaned the solution and the problem went away. HTH